# Bochner Integral: Approximability

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

**Problem**

Given a measure space $\Omega$ and a Banach space $E$.

Consider a Bochner measurable function $S_n\to F$.

Then it admits an approximation from nearly below:
$$\|S_n(\omega)\|\leq \vartheta\|F(\omega)\|:\quad S_n\to F\quad(\vartheta>1)$$
*(This is sufficient for most cases regarding proofs.)*

Can it happen that it does not admit an approximation from below:
$$\|S_n(\omega)\|\leq\|F(\omega)\|:\quad S_n\to F$$
*(I'm just being curious wether it can actually fail.)*

**Constructions**

The only constructions I found so far are cutoff to bound an approximation:
$$E_n:=\{\|F_n\|\leq2\|F\|\}:\quad F'_n:=F_n\chi_{E_n}\implies\|F'_n\|\leq2\|F\|$$
and reset to obtain an increasing resp. decreasing approximation:
$$R^\pm_n:=\{\|F_n\|\gtrless\|F'_{n-1}\|\}:\quad F'_n:=F_n\chi_{\Omega_n}+F'_{n-1}\chi_{\Omega_n^\complement}\implies\|F_n'\|\updownarrow\|F'_{n+1}\|$$
Apart from these truncation seems less relevant here:
$$\Omega_n\uparrow\Omega:\quad F'_n:=\chi_{\Omega_n}\implies\|F'_n\|\uparrow\|F\|$$

Comment: You can at least get (and this is sufficient for most purposes) $\Vert S_n \Vert \leq 2 \cdot \Vert F \Vert$ by considering $S_n ' := S_n \chi_{E_n}$ with $E_n := \{ \Vert S_n \Vert \leq 2 \Vert F \Vert \}$ (you will have to check that $\bigcup E_n = \Omega$ because of $S_n \to F$ pointwise). Of course, you can replace $2$ by any constant larget than $1$.

Comment: Mmh yes, that's even better! Still, can it happen that no sequence can converge from really below?

Comment: I just found a proof here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145195/approximation-of-a-strongly-measurable-function-by-a-sequence-of-simple-function) that one can always find an "approximation from below" as you wanted :)

Comment: @PhoemueX: Oh great, let me read that.

Comment: @C-Star-Puppy, do you have a references for these 'constructions' you found? I am looking at a proof for the fact that $\mathcal{S}(\mu;X)$ is dense in $L_p(\mu;X)$ for $p\in[1.\infty]$ which uses the *exact* construction as you have used - I am trying to understand the idea behind this construction.

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames: I am not sure anymore where I found them exactly, but it was certainly one of the following references, all of which addressing the "Bochner integral": Bochner, "Integration von Funktionen, deren Werte die Elemente eines Vektorraums sind" (Original article!). Cohn, Measure Theory, Appendix E Bochner Integral (see answer below). Yosida, Functional Analysis, Chapter V, Section 4 Pettis' Theorem and Section 5 Bochner Integral (great work on functional analysis, particular on its locally convex aspects). ...

Comment: ...  Amann and Escher, Analysis III, Chapter X, Section 1 and 2. (I don't recommend reading this work though, as it was overly technical and it was actually this reason that made me start the threads here in Stackexchange.) ...

Comment: ... Aside these references, I recommend highly reading on the very powerful machinary via direct integrals. I highly recommend herefore: A. E. Nussbaum, "Reduction theory for unbounded closed operators in Hilbert spaces."

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames: I hope these help you further with your work and let me know if you need further help! :)

Comment: Thanks for this incredible list - some I have already been trawling through, others not. I'll be sure to follow up with any issues - and thanks for getting back to me on so old a question!

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames: No problem, my pleasure. Sure, let me know when you need help. Glad to be able to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a modified version from: [Cohn: Measure Theory](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6956-8)*

Enumerate a countable dense set:
$$\#S\leq\mathfrak{n}:\quad S=\{s_1,\ldots\}\quad(\overline{S}=F\Omega)$$

Regard the finite subsets:
$$S_K:=\{s_1,\ldots,s_K\}$$

Construct the domains by:
$$A_k:=A_n(s_k):=\{\omega:\|s_k\|\leq\|F(\omega)\|\}\cap\{\omega:\|F(\omega)-s_k\|<\tfrac{1}{n}\}$$

And sum up their disjoint parts:
$$A_k':=A_k\setminus\left(\bigcup_{l=1}^{k-1}A_l\right):\quad F_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{K=n}s_k\chi_{A_k'}$$
*(Note that the supports are clearly measurable.)*